# jQuery validate on multi steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am creating a multi step form with the jQuery validate plugin and I am struggling with the validation on further steps.

If I hide the other steps of the form, the validation works correctly, however it just doesn't work when you have passed a certain step. For example, validation works on step 1, but when you reach step 2 and click "Next" it ignores the validation.

This is what I have currently:

```
    $("a#step1_button").on("click", function(e){

    // Validation //

    $('#application_form_form').validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            first_name: "Please answer this question",
            last_name: "Please answer this question"
        },
        ignore: ".ignore"
    });

    if ( $('#application_form_form').valid() == true ) {
        $('#step1').slideUp(500);
        $('#step2').delay(700).slideDown(500);
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});

$("a#step2_button").on("click", function(e){

    // Validation //

    $('#application_form_form').validate({
        rules: {
            reference_first_name: "required",
            reference_last_name: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            reference_first_name: "Please answer this question",
            reference_last_name: "Please answer this question"
        },
        ignore: ".ignore"
    });

    if ( $('#application_form_form').valid() == true ) {
        $('#step2').slideUp(500);
        $('#step3').delay(700).slideDown(500);
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Could anyone help with this and lead me to how I can sort this?

Many thanks.

Comment: $("a#step2_button").on("click", function(e) replace this with $('body').on('click','a#step2_button',function(e)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this - I have changed this and unfortunately this has no baring on the validation working on step 2.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?